# Instantiated Object Not Moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

Below is a class attached to a prefab object that gets Instantiated in the game but an up force is not applied to the object which the code below is trying to do instead I am getting this error.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object **at line 15**

Which is

```
rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

.

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightBulbLeft : MonoBehaviour {

//public GameObject LeftLB;


Rigidbody2D rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 15f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Start()
{
  rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 15f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

The `GetComponent<T>` method returns the component attached to an object. You need to assign `rb` to your Rigidbody before applying the force.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to get the `RigidBody2D` attached to the `LightBulbLeft` component. In that case, you would do:

```
rb = gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
```

As your code exists now, you are trying to get the `RigidBody2D` from a non-instantiated `RigidBody2D`.